# subprocess.run().stdout.read() returns CompletedProcess not a string

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

I'm using `subprocess` to get the output of the command line `bitwarden` tool to redirect it to `albert` (a launcher for linux). I'm using:

```
returned_user = subprocess.run(["bw", "get", "username", query, "--raw", "--session", session_key], text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, check=True).stdout.read()
```

Checking `type(returned_user)` gives `CompletedProcess`. How do I get the `stdout` as a string? `subprocess.check_output` returns a `CompletedProcess` too.

Everything done in Python 3.9.1.

Comment: Please take the [tour], it should clarify the concepts of StackOverflow to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

referring to https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, you missed
capture_output=True in the parameters.
i use python 3.7.3 (on my beagelbone):

just try on the python shell:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> command = "echo 123"  # your command here.
>>> result = subprocess.run(command, text=True, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
>>> user = 'unknown'
>>> print (user)
unknown
>>> if result.returncode == 0:
...     user = result.stdout.strip()
... 
>>> print (user)
123
>>>
```

Best Regards,
Bernd