# Python compare CompletedProcess

Tags: python

I have the following python script

```
        get = int(subprocess.run(["electrum","getbalance"]))
          if get > 0:
          print("something")
```

I get the following error
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'CompletedProcess'

The output of getbalance is :
{
"confirmed": "0.000001"
}

How can i compare if the balance is higher then 0 and print something ?

Comment: I don`t understand why do you try to convert subprocess.run to integer. Can you upload the whole code?

Comment: Possible duplicate or related - [subprocess.run().stdout.read() returns CompletedProcess not a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65540013/1324033)

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_out` instead. A byte-object will return if the execution is successful.

Answer (score 1):

The `run` function returns an instance of `subprocess.CompletedProcess` class.

[As per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess), you can use `stdout` property to get the Captured stdout from the child process. Note that this will return a bytes sequence(Since `run()` was not called with an encoding, errors, or `text=True`)

Also to to capture the `stdout` and `stderr` pass `capture_output=True`  to `run` function.

Example:

```
>>> from subprocess import run
>>> completed_process = run(['powershell.exe', '-c', 'Write-Output "Hello"'], capture_output=True)
>>> type(completed_process)
<class 'subprocess.CompletedProcess'>
>>> completed_process.stdout
b'Hello\r\n'
>>> type(completed_process.stdout)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
output = subprocess.run(your_command_here, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

This will return a "CompletedProcess". Then you can check if everything went good doing:

```
if(output.returncode == 0):
    # do stuffs
```

And looking at the output you say your command is returning `{ "confirmed": "0.000001" }` I guess python will use it as a JSON. So you can get the "0.000001" value with:

```
import json
data = output.stdout
data = json.loads(data)
what_you_want = data['confirmed']
```

So the code looks like this:

```
import json
output = subprocess.run(your_command_here, capture_output=True, text=True)
if(output.returncode == 0):
    data = output.stdout
    data = json.loads(data)
    what_you_want = data['confirmed']
```

PS: I did not try this code, I don't know if it runs.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, Thank you very much!